# python multithreading global varible issue

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

i'm trying to find the first 2000 prime numbers
i already have 1000 but i need to find all the others
with parallel calculation

i try to make 4 threads that every each one of them check the number with 250 numbers prime numbers
from my array of 1000 prime numbers and if one of the thread get un-prime number he need to tell to all
threads to stop and if the number pass all the threads checks the number will add to prime number array

for now from some reason the for loop at my check() function doesn't work

```
import threading 
numOfThreads=4
arr =[]
number=1
flag=0

def initArr(arr,number):
    while len(arr) != 1000:
        number=number+1
        count=0
        for i in range(2, (number // 2 + 1)):
            if number % i == 0:
                count = count + 1
                break
        if count == 0 and number != 1:
            arr.append(number)

def check(start,end,number):
    global flag
    global arr
    for num in range (start , end):
        if number % arr[num] == 0:
            flag=-1

        if flag == -1:
             continue

initArr(arr,number)

flagstart = 0
threads = list()
count=arr[len(arr)-1]
jobs = []
while len(arr) != 2000:
    for index in range(0,numOfThreads):
        start=int((index-1) * len(arr) / numOfThreads)
        end=int((index-1) * len(arr) / numOfThreads)
        if index == 0:
            start=0
        if index == numOfThreads:
            end=len(arr)
        thread = threading.Thread(target=check(start,end,count))
        jobs.append(thread)
        if flagstart == 0:
            flagstart = -1
            for j in jobs:
                j.start()
    if flag == 0:
        arr.append(count)
    elif flag == -1 :
        flag=0
    count = count+1
```

Comment: I don't know the answer, but _Note!_ threads never run in parallel in the most popular Python implementation. Google for "Python" and "GIL" to learn more.

Comment: maybe do you know how i can run in parallel 4 processes in while loop and every time 
they will run the same function bet with different arguments ?

Comment: Sorry, I have no experience writing Python programs that spawn child processes.